# Clicking a button on a windows from from a webform

Tags: c#, winforms, webforms

I have created a windows form program that does some Business Intelligence but have subsequently needed to access this via a webform. I am fairly new to programming so I don't know what can be achieved here. But essentially I am wanting someone to go on to the net and when the user presses a button it sends a message to the windows form executable in a file and tells it to run and then press a button on the form, which runs a method to generate images of graphs. Is this possible?

Here is the relevant code.

In the webform I have this button.

```
protected void rolloutSmartSheets(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = string.Format("Starting processes");
        ltMessage.Text = message;
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"P:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Smartsheet\SmartsheetAPI\obj\Debug\SmartSheetAPI.exe";
        process.Start();
        message = string.Format("Ended all processes");
        ltMessage.Text = message;
    }
```

That runs the executable but it opens the windows form and I imagine if the executable is sitting on another computer wouldn't that open on that computer? In which case i want it to tell it to press this button on the windows form which runs the method I need and then the user doesn't need to worry about it.

```
    public void commitToDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        commitToDataBase();
    }
```

Comment: A webform can't start processes on a client's pc. The form is processed at server side. It would be a huge security hole if such things would be possible.

Comment: The way to do this is use a database, your winform can share the web apps database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to have the clients install something in advance, you can provide this functionality using a custom protocol handler.

Example protocol handler from [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   alert
      (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
         (Default) = "alert.exe,1"
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1"
```

Then add a link onto your webform like this

```
href="alert://test"
```

As long as the client has the handler installed, both in the registry and the executable file, it will run `C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe`, passing "test" to it as the first paramater.

You can easily change this to provide the ability to run the local graph generator, and pass any parameters from the webform you might need.